# btrfs compress existing data with snapshots

Tags: compression, btrfs, deduplication

I'm runninga a btrfs raid1 on 5 8 TB disks, where primarily urbackup stores backups to. Urbackup uses snapshots extensively. `compsize` produces the following output:

```
Processed 106161732 files, 57335496 regular extents (190449694 refs), 63766108 inline.
Type       Perc     Disk Usage   Uncompressed Referenced
TOTAL       78%       13T          16T          58T
none       100%       11T          11T          47T
zlib        29%      1.4T         5.0T          10T
```

For a while I ran btrfs with compression and afterwards disabled it. As `compsize` now shows, compression can reduce the disk usage considerably (see line zlib). So I wonder how to compress the existing data without destroying the snapshot structure of the existing data. Due to performance reasons I would also prefer using zstd compression instead of zlib. System is Debian 5.7.10 x86_64 with btrfs-progs 4.20.1 if that matters.
Options I analysed:

- `btrfs fi defrag -czstd` would destroy the snapshot structure.
- Mounting with `force-compress=zstd` and `btrfs fi balance` will not compress rebalanced extents, it will just copy them as they are.

Is there anything I can do to compress the existing data without destroying the snapshot structure?

Ideas:

- Can I somehow copy data to another compressed btrfs partition with keeping the snapshot structure intact?
- What about defrag and offline deduplication with dduper? Will it recreate the snapshot structure?